# Onchange from dropdown -> from field

Tags: javascript, html, field, onchange, dropdown

I really don't know anything about JS. I made one calc in excel but I wat it on my www. I decided to copy examples from .net. Step by step I changed most of the things. Now I'm stuck...

I have 3 fields on the begin van my form:

```
<li id="li_14">
<label class="description" for="cena_on">CON </label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 1 -->
€ <input id="cena_on" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<li id="li_15">
<label class="description" for="cena_pb">CPB</label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 2 -->
€ <input id="cena_pb" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<li id="li_16">
<label class="description" for="cena_lpg">CLPG </label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 3 -->
€ <input id="cena_lpg" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
```

This fields are required to make all calculations correctly.
Later on user need to use dropdown menu to choose one option. Values of this options are taked from this 3 first fields.

```
        <div>
<select id="element_21" onChange="pali"> 
              <option value="cena_on1" >ON</option>
              <option value="cena_pb1" >PB</option>
              <option value="cena_lpg1" >LPG</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Because I cannot make JS on my own I tried a lot of examples to make it, I tried to set somehow that cena_on = cena_on1. On the begin that was totally different but after 20++ test all of the values are weird and I am confused as hell. :S

How to make it for example:
if cena_on from field 1 is 1
cena_bp is 2
and cena_lpg is 3

Then dropdown option ON is also 1, PB 2 and lpg 3? Then I can take this selected value to my calculations.

```
  var PAL = (element_21 * 12);
  $('#PAL').text(PAL);
```

Comment: I have tried to understand your post/question for 3 times, but still can't understand your goal.

Comment: The only way to get the task done is to learn JS and HTML. You can't just code without learning first.

Comment: You can get the numeric values you're looking for from the `<select>` element by checking its `selectedIndex` instead of its value.

Comment: J.Meijer - sorry. My english is not perfect and also is hard to talk about sth what you dont know...

@Teemu - Right! Especialy if you have time for this and when you sure that you will use it in future - so not for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed to $ sign, I assume that you are using Jquery. So:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#element_21").change(function(){
  // Detect what option is selected (also remove 1 from its value)
  var fieldId="#" + $(this).val().replace("1","");

  // Jump to the input field with same id extracted above:
  var userinput= $(fieldId).val();

  //Do your calculations
  var PAL = (userinput * 12);
  $('#PAL').text(PAL);
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li_14">
<label class="description" for="cena_on">CON </label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 1 -->
€ <input id="cena_on" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<li id="li_15">
<label class="description" for="cena_pb">CPB</label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 2 -->
€ <input id="cena_pb" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<li id="li_16">
<label class="description" for="cena_lpg">CLPG </label>
<div>
<!-- HERE USER SET PRICE 3 -->
€ <input id="cena_lpg" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<br>

<div>
<select id="element_21"> 
      <option value="cena_on1" >ON</option>
      <option value="cena_pb1" >PB</option>
      <option value="cena_lpg1" >LPG</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Result:<br>
<div id="PAL"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to have live updates to final result when changing the `input` values, trigger a fake `onChange` on `<select>` as soon as you change the inputs:

```
$("#cena_on,#cena_pb,#cena_lpg").on("input paste keyup",function(){
   $("#element_21").trigger("change");
})
```

Comment: I tried whit my code and I mess it up. I made short version to test and there is one error and sth doesnt work[link](https://jsfiddle.net/uv05Lpd6/7/)[link]

Comment: You have to do 2 things more: 1- remove onChange from select element. Also wrap js code inside `$(document).ready` . I have updated the answer. Please run the snippet.

Comment: Hey. Thank you. I mix it with the rest of my code and it seems to work correctly right now. One morequestion. I had my code with onchange to get result right after changes in form. Now i can change everything but I need to go back to dropdown to recalculate all fields. How to make live results or how to ad "calculate" button. First option is nicer for me.

Thank you one more time!!

Comment: Ok. I have updated the answer by adding a code to the end of answer, to trigger fake changes on `<select>` element when needed. (You can vote up my answer for this change.)

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
If you WANT - because you solve my problem already, can you tell me how to change NaN to something else (when not all fields are filled) or maybe alert - that field is filled wrong or something?